# AWS intermittent slow ssh and GET requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

we have few EC2 server on AWS but one one particular server we are noticing odd issues. First of all, SSH takes tens of seconds but only happens intermittently. Secondly, get request to the server also takes tens of seconds, but again it happens intermittently. We checked the stats on the server and everything looks fine. CPU average is around 7% and 25GB of free ram. 
Here is the response from ss -s:

```
Total: 2553 (kernel 0)
TCP:   12015 (estab 2342, closed 9189, orphaned 478, synrecv 0, timewait 9188/0), ports 0

Transport      Total     IP        IPv6
*               0        -         -
RAW             0        0         0
UDP             4        4         0
TCP             2826     2765      61
INET            2830     2769      61
FRAG            0        0         0
```

And breakdown of current connection status:

```
      1 established)
      1 Foreign
      6 LISTEN
     62 LAST_ACK
    136 SYN_RECV
    155 CLOSING
    251 FIN_WAIT1
   1078 FIN_WAIT2
   2197 ESTABLISHED
   8229 TIME_WAIT
```

We have ruled out DNS issue, as it happens when we try to access it via it's hostname or the ip address. There are no load balancer in front of that server. We do use Route53 for routing purposes, but I don't see any issue with that.

Using AB to do get requests:
Run #1

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.6.1
Server Hostname:        my.hidden.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /debug
Document Length:        43 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   104.415 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      162304 bytes
HTML transferred:       21500 bytes
Requests per second:    4.79 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       208.829 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       208.829 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.52 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      134  160  35.7    154     709
Processing:    39   49   8.2     48     127
Waiting:       39   49   8.2     48     127
Total:        178  209  38.6    203     809

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    203
  66%    209
  75%    212
  80%    215
  90%    225
  95%    244
  98%    273
  99%    302
 100%    809 (longest request)
```

Run #2

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.6.1
Server Hostname:        my.hidden.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /debug
Document Length:        43 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   515.608 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      162284 bytes
HTML transferred:       21500 bytes
Requests per second:    0.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1031.216 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1031.216 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.31 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      136  980 1251.8    164    5575
Processing:    39   51  33.0     48     730
Waiting:       39   51  33.0     48     730
Total:        180 1031 1258.7    216    6306

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    216
  66%    243
  75%   2839
  80%   2850
  90%   2874
  95%   2903
  98%   2935
  99%   2992
 100%   6306 (longest request)
```

Run #3

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.6.1
Server Hostname:        my.hidden.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /debug
Document Length:        43 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   417.639 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      162320 bytes
HTML transferred:       21500 bytes
Requests per second:    1.20 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       835.279 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       835.279 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.38 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      137  781 1140.0    162    5053
Processing:    38   54  56.6     49    1281
Waiting:       38   54  56.6     49    1281
Total:        179  835 1141.2    213    5104

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    213
  66%    233
  75%    334
  80%   2835
  90%   2872
  95%   2915
  98%   3030
  99%   3137
 100%   5104 (longest request)
```

Run #4

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.6.1
Server Hostname:        my.hidden.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /debug
Document Length:        43 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   104.806 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      162250 bytes
HTML transferred:       21500 bytes
Requests per second:    4.77 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       209.611 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       209.611 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.51 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      135  160  13.8    157     227
Processing:    39   50   8.8     48     159
Waiting:       39   50   8.8     48     159
Total:        179  209  17.7    206     331

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    206
  66%    212
  75%    216
  80%    219
  90%    230
  95%    240
  98%    266
  99%    275
 100%    331 (longest request)
```

Run #5

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.6.1
Server Hostname:        my.hidden.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,2048,256

Document Path:          /debug
Document Length:        43 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   110.983 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      162282 bytes
HTML transferred:       21500 bytes
Requests per second:    4.51 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       221.967 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       221.967 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.43 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      132  170 149.3    159    3460
Processing:    38   52  25.8     49     589
Waiting:       38   52  25.8     49     589
Total:        177  222 152.6    208    3532

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    208
  66%    217
  75%    222
  80%    227
  90%    240
  95%    257
  98%    282
  99%    336
 100%   3532 (longest request)
```

Comment: Exact OS version? What is the same output from an instance without the issue?

Comment: How does ping look for that instance? Maybe you have a bad neighbor

Comment: We are using amazon linux version 2015.09. The ping times are comparable between all nodes. I ran ab with some commands. I have attached the results above.